# Symfony annotation error on custom field

Tags: annotations, doctrine, symfony

I'm new bie to Symfony 3, I couldn't find a favorable solution online. Therefore I'm raising this question.

My Entity Class as follows:

```
// src/AppBundle/Entity/TimeTable.php
namespace AppBundle\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;


/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="time_table")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\TimeTableRepository")
 * @UniqueEntity(fields={"dateid","trend"}, message="Duplicate Entry")
 */

class TimeTable
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;


    /**
     * @ORM\dateid
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    private $dateid;

    /**
     * @ORM\trend
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    private $trend;

    /**
     * @ORM\mmpy
     * @ORM\Column(type="decimal")
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    private $mmpy;

    public function getDateid()
    {
        return $this->dateid;
    }

    public function setDateid($dateid)
    {
        $this->date = $dateid;
    }

    public function getTrend()
    {
        return $this->trend;
    }

    public function setTrend($trend)
    {
        $this->trend = $trend;
    }

    public function getMmpy()
    {
        return $this->mmpy;
    }

    public function setMmpy($mmpy)
    {
        $this->mmpy = $mmpy;
    }
}
```

and When I run the following command : `php bin/console doctrine:schema:validate`

it throws me following error:

```
[Semantical Error] The annotation "@Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\dateid" in property AppBundle\Entity\TimeTable::$dateid do
  es not exist, or could not be auto-loaded.
```

Any idea how what cause the issue and how to overcome it?

FYI: I'm using Symfony 3.2

,Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Because it is not a [valid Doctrine annotation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html)

You also, have

```
trend
mmpy
```

They don't appear as valid as well. Where did you get those from. Maybe an old article?

Comment: sorry this was my mistake, because I created this file manually; but when I generated the via symfony command line it worked fine. thanks for your time.

Comment: You should either provide that as an answer or close your question.